# Convert date time string to different format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, object, javascript-objects

I have a date time string stored in an object as such:

```
submittedEventObj = {
'description' : result.event_summary
'start' : {
'dateTime' : result.start_time,
'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
}
};
```

`result.start_time` is equal to the string `'2023-06-30T09:00'`

This date time string is stored in the format of `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm`. However, I need to have this string converted to the format of `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`. I need to add the `:00` at the end basically. The function that I am passing this object into requires the date time to be in the format which includes seconds, but the string that I receive from the user is stored without the seconds. I was wondering if there is a way for me to take the string given to me by the user which is without seconds and convert it to the format with seconds so that I can store that string in the object and pass it to the function.

Thanks

Comment: If that's _really_ all you need, just add the `:00` yourself? E.g. ```'dateTime' : `${result.start_time}:00`.``` or just do that templating as part of the function call argument.